Changing characteristics of a zip file created
I have created a POC which creates a zip containing a xml file whose characteristics is currently "UTF8". I want it to be "Descriptor UTF8". If someone has faced similar issue do assist.
Expected format
Current format
Below mentioned is the code for POC:
const yazl = require('yazl');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
 
function test(
    location,
    ackId,
    responseContent,
    responsezipFileName,
    responsefileName
) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const zipFile = new yazl.ZipFile();
 
        // Ensure the content is a Buffer with UTF-8 encoding
        const contentBuffer = Buffer.isBuffer(responseContent) ? responseContent : Buffer.from(responseContent, 'utf8');
 
        // Function to convert Date to DOS date/time format
        function dateToDosTime(d) {
            return {
                date: ((d.getFullYear() - 1980) << 9) | ((d.getMonth() + 1) << 5) | d.getDate(),
                time: (d.getHours() << 11) | (d.getMinutes() << 5) | (d.getSeconds() / 2)
            };
        }
 
        const now = new Date();
        const { date: dosDate, time: dosTime } = dateToDosTime(now);
 
        // Add the file to the ZIP, ensuring the filename is UTF-8 encoded
        zipFile.addBuffer(contentBuffer, responsefileName, {
            mtime: now,
            mode: 0o100666, // FAT-compatible mode
            compress: true,
            forceZip64Format: false,
            dosPermissions: 0x20, // Archive bit set (normal file)
            lastModFileTime: dosTime,
            lastModFileDate: dosDate
        });
 
        // Finalize the ZIP file and write to the output location
        const outputZipPath = path.join(location, `${responsezipFileName}`);
        const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(outputZipPath);
 
        zipFile.outputStream.pipe(writeStream)
            .on('close', () => {
                console.info(`${responsezipFileName} zip file created for FAT system.`);
                resolve();
            })
            .on('error', (err) => {
                console.error('Error in creating zip file', err);
                reject(err);
            });
 
        zipFile.end();
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error inside test:::', error);
        throw new Error(error.message || 'Unknown error occurred');
    });
}

// Example usage
test(
    'Downloads',
    '12345',
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <note>
      <to>John</to>
      <from>Jane</from>
      <heading>Reminder</heading>
      <body>Don't forget the meeting at 10 AM tomorrow!</body>
      <date>2024-09-05</date>
      <unicodeExample></unicodeExample>
    </note>
    `,
    'response.zip',
    'response.xml'
).then(() => {
    console.log('ZIP file creation successful.');
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error('ZIP file creation failed:', err);
});


Characteristics of zipped file to be "Descriptor UTF8". I have tried several zipping libraries, none worked.

Both are same, name might be difference bases on OS

@YuvarajM I guess it is an assumption only, because I have not found any article or documentation supporting this. Or if you have any article do share.

The type is based on the file before zipping.  What is the issue that you need to change the type?  The ZIP specification basically clones the file as it is loaded on the file system using the block and cylinder size.

@jdweng In both cases file is exactly the same, it's just that expected result is coming from an old system which is coded in Java and for this current code automation tests are getting failed.

ZIP specification has different versions and optional sections. To speed up the algorithm many zip utilities clone the number of sectors and cylinders of the disk into the zip structure. Have found that issues when the disk that was used in creating the zip is not the same structure as zip that is used to unzip.  Libraries/Utilities like 7Zip work all the time.  Other libraries/Utilities like the Windows and Net have some issues.  The optional sections of specifications on how to add/delete files to an existing zip often are the causes of errors.   I do not think your error is due to the type.
